# How to delete a storeage item using a local reference?

Tags: solidity

I have a reference to a storage item:

```
MyData storage myData = /* ... */;
```

How can I use `myData` to clear up that storage item?

I've tried

```
delete myData;
```

but this fails to compile, because Solidity assumes that I want to clear the `myData` reference and not the referenced storage.

Comment: So don't use `myData`. Delete the actual item.

Comment: I'm confused. Are you saying that it's impossible?